# HTML images adjustment

Tags: html, css, image

I have a problem put 4 images into 1 page, I want the images sequence like the below sample:
[image]

Now my coding just can show the image move to left-hand side, below is my sample coding:

```html
<style>
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

<div class="4_page" style='height: 50%; width: 25%;text-align: center; object-fit: contain'>
    <img src="hebahan New material.png">
</div>


<div class="4_page" style='height: 50%; width: 25%;text-align: center; object-fit: contain'>
    <img src="logo_test.png">
</div>

<div class="4_page" style='height: 50%; width: 25%;text-align: center; object-fit: contain'>
    <img src="logo_test.png">
</div>

<div class="4_page" style='height: 50%; width: 25%;text-align: center; object-fit: contain'>
    <img src="logo_test.png">
</div>

</style>
```

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Please [validate your HTML](https://html5.validator.nu/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is `<div>` tag should not be under `<style></style>` tags. Check if this solved your problem. I could have formatted it as below, I have used a table instead --

The main index.html HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>YourTitle</title>
      <link rel ="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!--For responsiveness-->
   </head>

   <body>
      <table class="img-cont"> <!-- The table will automatically arrange images on basis of height you define. Always close table inside a <div> tag if you are displaying other info too.--> 
         <tr>
             <th><img src="hebahan New material.png"></th>
             <th><img src="logo_test.png"></th>
         </tr>

         <tr>
             <th><img src="logo_test.png"></th>
             <th><img src="logo_test.png"></th>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

My external `style.css` will have:

```
.img-cont {
   width:100%;
   height:100%; /*only if there is nothing to show other than images*/
}

img {
   max-width:100% /*Adjust accordingly*/
   max-height:100% 
}
```

This will also minimize your code and enhance speed.
Select the answer if it worked.

Comment: But if I print, 4 images cannot print in 1 page, it will divide 2 images per page.

Comment: Print preview cannot show 4 images on 1 page.

Comment: Check at vedicbooks.cf it is made using table tag.

Comment: you may check code at https://github.com/vaidicbooks/xyzabcrandom.github.io

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to use CSS instead of inline styling.
2. The class shall not start with a number.
3. Adjust the height as per your requirement.

```css
.col-25{
border:2px solid yellow;
display:inline-block;
height: 400px;
width: 49%;
box-sizing:border-box;
text-align:center;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-25">
    <img src="hebahan New material.png">
</div>


<div class="col-25" >
    <img src="logo_test.png">
</div>

<div class="col-25" >
    <img src="logo_test.png">
</div>

<div class="col-25" >
    <img src="logo_test.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But if I print, 4 images cannot print in 1 page, it will divide 2 images per page.

Comment: Adjust the height so that it will fit into your page. The page size varies as per your requirement.

Comment: Can make it autofit height into the div, because I have many images cannot 1 by 1 to adjust the height.